# VueJS realtime check disk

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, vue.js

I am new in VueJS, i want to check disk realtime using VueJS but my code not working for realtime, needed to resfresh the page, I don't know why

here is my script :

```
var vo = new Vue({
    el: '.data_env',
    data () {
        return {
          data  : {}
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        axios
        .get(BASE_URL+'clients/get_disk_size')
        .then(response => (
            this.data   = response.data
            ))
    }
})
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: What is your `BASE_URL` prop, and why in mounted, also `el` is bounded to ID, not a Class.

Comment: BASE_URL is link to my project ex : 'http://localhost/projects', which life cycle shoud i put it ?

Comment: Where did you define it?

Comment: footer template master ... BASE_URL is working fine dude ... i've been check it

Comment: put the axios call in `created`, catch the promise, and console.log the error and look at console in google developer tools(f12) for logs.

Comment: still not working , 
here is my component , by the way https://pastebin.com/DAqsZD6y and here i've been try https://pastebin.com/5eR9rSWr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195835/discussion-between-0x00b0-and-deda).

Answer (score 3):

You need to refresh the page because mounted() executed only during creation of the component.
If you have variable and want to fetch a new data when this variable changed, you can use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) or computed. If you want to get a new data whenever it changed on server side you need to use websocket.

Answer (score 1):

According to Vue lifecycle,if you want to fetch result on realtime you should put you code **inside computed and watch property**.
If any changes occur it will do two way binding with Html element and show changes without refreshing page

For More info go through this link - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html